# Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in url - Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

i created an ajax file that pass ID in the page. and that page has a query. and i got an error. I try to know what is my error and some site said i have to define my template and require the wp-load.php, but some site said that i have to do it on function.php. and i really don't know what to do. i'm new in wordpress woocommerce.

> Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in  xxxx/xxxx

Here is my Page (get-fabric.php)

```
   <?php  


    if(!empty($_POST['select_colour']))
    {
        $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1000,
        'product_cat'    => 'fabric'


        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);


            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            global $product;
            $regular_price = $product->get_price_html();

            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $query->post->ID ), 'product' );
                echo '  <div class="col-md-3 fabric-active" data-fabcode="32860">
                <div class="fabric-cloth">
                    <div class="fabric-data">
                        <img src="'.$image[0].'" class="img-responsive cursor-on" />
                        <div class="fabric-code">
                            <p>'.$product->post->post_title.'</p>
                            <span>'.$regular_price.'</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
            endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 fabric-active" data-fabcode="32860">
                <div class="fabric-cloth">
                    <div class="fabric-data">
                        <img src="'.$image[0].'" class="img-responsive cursor-on" />
                        <div class="fabric-code">
                            <p>'.$product->post->post_title.'</p>
                            <span>'.$regular_price.'</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <?php
     }
  ?>
```

Comment: There is some other errors in your code. 1) you should replace `global $product;` by `$product = wc_get_product($query->post->ID);` … 2) you should replace `$product->post->post_title` by `$query->post->post_title`…

Comment: okay LoicTheAztec i already change it, thanks for the help bro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are calling this url directly, which is not how WordPress ajax is intended to work, you can still get this code to run by adding this php code

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

to the top of the file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins I know this says Ajax in plugins but this is also what you would do if developing a custom theme to keep your code WordPress-y.

Comment: Thanks JasonB for quick response, i tried to put it and it works. but can i know its safe to put those code?. because i found some site its not safe?. and i already saw that link but i really don't know how im gonna do it. to check my other question to see my ajax file [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373453/wordpress-and-woocommerce-passing-variables-with-ajax )

Comment: You just need to do some homework. Use the WP codex and the PHP docs and learn what the code is doing. The two lines of code in this answer just load the file wp-load.php from your own site so they don't introduce any errors on their own. You whould be using the framework's methods of creating ajax requests and using nonce's to help make sure that the request is valid. See this too: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214587/security-blocking-direct-access-of-php-files

Comment: If you have some more stuff wired up and working but have a specific safety or security question, I'd post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro. sadly they just turn over this kind of project to me, and im new to wordpress. so i really don't know how to do it, and they just give me 1 month to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

The page you have created has no relation with WordPress. Neither you are including anything nor you have declared any global variables. In that case not only WP_Query, it will never find any WordPress method.

For this case, there are 2 solutions

1. (Recommended) Include header and footer by using respective functions.

   [get_header()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) && [get_footer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)
2. Declare the global variable before using it.

   global $wp_query;

Hope this helps you in someway :)